# Selecting SUM of DISTINCT rows in a joined query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, orders and orderitems. I'm making a report of sales by date which needs to include the total costprice and sellingprice of each orderitem on each date and the total deliverycost for each order on each date:

table: order

```
orderid    date          deliverycost
1          2000-01-01    5
2          2000-01-01    3
3          2000-01-02    0
4          2000-01-02    4
```

table: orderitem

```
orderitemdid    orderid    costprice    sellingprice
1               1          10           12
2               1          2            4
3               2          10           12
4               3          5            6
5               3          4            10
6               4          1            2
```

I'm looking for a query which will provide the following output:

```
date          costprice   sellingprice   deliverycost
2000-01-01    22          28             8    
2000-01-02    10          18             4
```

I have tried the following SQL:

```
        SELECT
            SUM(`orderitem`.`costprice`) AS `costprice`,
            SUM(`orderitem`.`sellingprice`) AS `sellingprice`,
            SUM(`order`.`delivery`) AS `delivery`,
            DATE(`order`.`date`) AS `date`,
        FROM
            `order`
        INNER JOIN
            `orderitem`
        ON
            (`order`.`orderid` = `orderitem`.`orderid`)
        GROUP BY
            `date`
        ORDER BY
            `date`
```

The problem is that I end up with the delivery price multiplied by the number of order items, so I'm looking to do the SUM() on the `order`.`delivery` before the join happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be related to the improper use of quotes 
don't use single quote for column name but when need  use backtics

```
   SELECT
        SUM(`orderitem`.`costprice`) as costprice,
        SUM(`orderitem`.`sellingprice`) as sellingprice,
        SUM(`order`.`delivery`) as delivery,
        DATE(`order`.`confirmdate`) as `date`,
    FROM  `order`
    INNER JOIN  `orderitem`    ON `order`.`orderid` = `orderitem`.`orderid`
    GROUP BY  `date`
    ORDER BY `date`
```

in your case should work also avoiding backtics  because you don't have separated  column name and reserved  word

```
   SELECT
        SUM(orderitem.costprice) as costprice,
        SUM(orderitem.sellingprice) as sellingprice,
        SUM(order.delivery) as delivery,
        DATE(order.confirmdate) as date,
    FROM  order
    INNER JOIN  orderitem    ON order.orderid = orderitem.orderid
    GROUP BY  date
    ORDER BY date
```

and for avoid cartesian product  you could  join the aggregated  tables

```
   SELECT
        SUM(t.costprice) as costprice,
        SUM(t.sellingprice) as sellingprice,
        SUM(order.delivery) as delivery,
        DATE(order.confirmdate) as date,
    FROM  order
    INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT 
        orderitem.orderid
        SUM(orderitem.costprice) as costprice,
        SUM(orderitem.sellingprice) as sellingprice
        from orderitem
        group by  orderitem.orderid
      ) t ON order.orderid = t.orderid
    GROUP BY  date
    ORDER BY date
```

Comment: I've fixed the single quotes for backticks, but still get the same results... I tend to backtick everything out of habbit and because a lot of the SQL is generated.